# Let $T\colon \Bbb{R}^5\to\Bbb{R}^5$ be a linear operator such that $T^4\neq 0$ but $T^5=0$. What is the rank of $T^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

> Let $T\colon \Bbb{R}^5\to\Bbb{R}^5$ be a linear operator such that $T^4\neq 0$ but $T^5=0$. What is the rank of $T^2$?

I'm studying for linear algebra exam.

I know the minimal polynomial of $T$ is $x^5$ which divides the characteristic polynomial, so there is only the eigenvalue $0$ with multiplicity $5$. I also know that the rank of $T$ is less than $5$.

My guess is that each additional $T$ you lose a dimension, so the rank of $T^2$ would be $3$ but I don't know how to prove it.

Any hints?

Edit, I do know Jordan form but I am supposed to prove this without Jordan form.

Comment: Do you know about Jordan canonical form?

Comment: @TedShifrin I do but this is before that, I don't think we can use it

Comment: OK, so your guess isn't really a guess :)

Comment: @TedShifrin Correct. :)

Comment: Maybe you can use that there is some vector $v$ such that $T^4v \not=0$ and take the matrix associated to T in the basis $\{v,Tv,T^2v,T^3v,T^4v\}$

Comment: Consider that zero is the only eigenvalue and perform some combinatorial consideration on the dimension of the eigenspaces associated with such eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the order of nilpotence of your operator is 5, you know there must be a vector $v$ such that $T^4v\not=0$ and you can prove the set $\{v,Tv,T^2v,T^3v,T^4v\}$ is LI, so it spans. Now take the matrix associated to that basis, it has all zeros except in the first subdiagonal, which contains 1's

Comment: This is basically Jordan normal form, but I think perhaps in disguise enough for my purposes. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't drop dimension, you'd have the equality $N(T^2)=N(T)$ ($N$ denoting nullspace or kernel). Then you should be able to see that $T^3x=0\iff T^2x=0\iff Tx=0$, so $N(T^3)=N(T)$. Etc.

Comment: <3 ${}{}{}{}{}$